# Structures not taking values

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm having an issue with an assignment. The task is to read a string from a txt file and compare it to an array of pointers to structures. If the string already appears then increase the count of that struct by 1, if not found, insert the string into the array with count 1. 
 The struct is defined:

```
struct wordfreq {
    int count;
    char *word;
}
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct wordfreq {
    int count;
    char *word;
};

typedef struct wordfreq wordfreq;

int mystrcmp(char *str1, char *str2);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, flag, current, spot;
    char *temp, *temp2;
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    wordfreq *wordsptr[1000];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments, exiting\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if (infile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening input file, exiting\n");
            return 2;
        }
        if (outfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening output file, exiting\n");
            return 3;
        }
    }
    current = 0;
    flag = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        wordsptr[i] = NULL;
    temp = (char *)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    while (fgets(temp, 20, infile) != NULL)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            if (temp[i] == '\n')
                temp[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s %d\n", temp, current);
        wordsptr[current] = (wordfreq *)malloc(sizeof(wordfreq));
        wordsptr[current]->word = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
        (*wordsptr[current]).word = temp;
        (*wordsptr[current]).count = 1;
        current++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < current; i++)
        printf("%d %s\n", (*wordsptr[i]).count, (*wordsptr[i]).word);




    free(temp);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        wordsptr[i] = NULL;
        free(wordsptr[i]);
    }
    if (infile != NULL)
        fclose(infile);
    if (outfile != NULL)
        fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}


int mystrcmp(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0' || str2[i] != '\0';i++)
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

A couple of stipulations: 
1) Have to initialize all pointers to null 
2) Have to use an array of pointers to structures

run:
./assign6 words.txt freq.txt

words.txt:

```
apple
orange
apple
orange
banana
banana
```

The output I'm receiving:
    1 banana
    1 banana
    1 banana
    1 banana
    1 banana
    1 banana

It's supposed to output the count of the string in the txt file and the string itself to the file specified by argv[2]. Please help!

Comment: `wordsptr[current]->word = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char)); (*wordsptr[current]).word = temp;`. That is not the way to copy a string. All that does is malloc some memory, throw it away and set `word` to point to the *same* `temp` buffer for *every* struct. Either use `strcpy` to copy from `temp` into the allocated `word`. Or use `strdup` to do the alloc and copy in one go.

Comment: `(*wordsptr[current]).word = temp;` --> `strcpy(wordsptr[current]->word,  temp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the address of temp, which is constantly updated with new values at every iteration, hence why you get the string of the last iteration in all structures here. This is caused by the following lines:

```
wordsptr[current]->word = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
(*wordsptr[current]).word = temp;
```

(*Which it is worth mentioning that this is also a memory leak because you lose the pointer to the heap memory.*)

You should instead use `strcpy()` or a similar method to copy the characters from `temp` to `wordsptr[current]->word`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake, CS student life. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Hunter, no problem. Just as a further suggestion, you should always check the returns of `malloc(...)` and `calloc(...)`. Not sure if your instructor has covered that, but they can return NULL if allocation failed, so it is best practice to check them and handle those situations gracefully to avoid getting a segmentation fault from trying to dereference a NULL pointer.